# Mi codigo se salta un gets()

Tags: c, vscode

**Gracias de antemano!**

A mi me ocurre el siguiente error y es que cuando yo quiero obtener un "String" en C me ocurre que se salta la linea de código y salta la obtención de código como en esta imagen sale:

[image: Imagen]

Y como se puede ver en donde dice "Por favor dime el nombre del virus" no obtiene el input y ahí es donde debería obtener el input.

Este es una pequeña parte de mi codigo que es la que falla:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void esUI()
{
    printf("Bienvenido!\n");
    printf("Por favor dime el nombre de tu virus:\n");
    char virusName[50];
    gets(virusName);
}
```

Comment: ¿Estás programando en C o en C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías publicar todo el código; sin embargo, te daré un código de ejemplo:

```
int main ()
{
    int op;
    char virusname[50];
    printf("Please, select your language\n1. English\n2.Spanish\n");
    scanf("%d", &op);
    if(op == 1)
    {
        printf("Por favor dime el nombre de tu virus:\n");
        gets(virusName);
    }
    else
    {
        //código en inglés.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ese código tendrá el mismo problema y eso se debe porqué el búfer del teclado está sucio. Es decir, cuando le pides al usuario que ingrese un lenguaje, la función scanf se ejecutará y dejará un salto de línea (`\n`) en el búfer. Entonces luego cuando se ejecute la función gets, no pausará el programa porqué el búfer debe estar vacío.

En C podríamos limpiar el búfer de esta manera:

```
while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

El código corregido quedaría así:

```
int main ()
{
    int op;
    char virusname[50];
    printf("Please, select your language\n1. English\n2.Spanish\n");
    scanf("%d", &op);
    //Limpiamos el búfer stdin después del scanf.
    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
    if(op == 1)
    {
        printf("Por favor dime el nombre de tu virus:\n");
        gets(virusName);
    }
    else
    {
        //código en inglés.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

De ese modo, la función gets ahora sí pausará el programa y no tendrás ningún problema.

Ahora te recomiendo no usar la función gets para leer cadenas, dado que no te permite especificar el tamaño del búfer y por ende, podría ocurrir un desbordamiento de búfer. Por ejemplo:

El tamaño del arreglo `virusname` es de 50 caracteres, si el usuario ingresa más de 50, se desbordará el búfer (`virusname`) y esto puede causar sobreescritura de memoria o hacer que el programa se bloquee al instante.

Una posible solución, es usar la función `fgets`:

```
printf("Por favor dime el nombre de tu virus:\n");
fgets(virusName, sizeof virusname, stdin);
```

Ahora, para no estar escribiendo mucho, podrías acortar más el código usando una macro:

```
#define fgets_(str) fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)
```

**Modo de uso:**

```
printf("Por favor dime el nombre de tu virus:\n");
fgets_(virusName);
```

Y así te ahorras estar escribiendo el `sizeof` y el `stdin`.